# SELECT * FROM city WHERE city LIKE '%value% %value%';

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mariadb

i have a Database with a lot of Cities and two Cities with similar Names.

**Oldenburg in Holstein** and **Oldenburg (Oldenburg)**

I get a City from URL

Example URL:

www.example.com/cityname/oldenburg-in-holstein

www.example.com/cityname/oldenburg-oldenburg

```
SELECT city FROM citynames WHERE city LIKE '%oldenburg%';
```

I make this Statement i get **Oldenburg in Holstein**

```
SELECT * FROM citynames WHERE city LIKE '%oldenburg%' AND LIKE '%oldenburg%'';
```

i get **Oldenburg in Holstein** again but if I make this Statement

```
SELECT city FROM citynames WHERE city LIKE '%oldenburg% %oldenburg%';
```

The Statement work! And i get **Oldenburg (Oldenburg)**
My question is can i use this statement or no?

Comment: You said it worked, then what's the question?

Comment: Because, I've never seen such a database query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With

```
SELECT * FROM citynames WHERE city LIKE '%oldenburg%' AND LIKE '%oldenburg%'';
```

you are asking the same thing twice: whether the city contains the string 'oldenburg'. This is not what you want.

With

```
SELECT city FROM citynames WHERE city LIKE '%oldenburg% %oldenburg%';
```

you are looking for a city that contains 'oldenburg' then after that at some point a blank, then after that at some point again the word 'oldenburg'. So yes, this is what you want. You'll find 'Oldenburg (Oldenburg)', but not 'Oldenburg in Holstein'.

As you are getting the city names from a URL where the parts of the city name are separated with `-`, that will be:

```
SELECT city FROM citynames WHERE city LIKE CONCAT('%', REPLACE(url, '-', '%'), '%');
```

BTW: Obviously you are using a collation that is not case sensitive. Otherwise you'd have to use `LIKE '%Oldenburg% %Oldenburg%'` in order to find 'Oldenburg (Oldenburg)' or `WHERE LOWER(city) LIKE ...`.

Comment: is not there any better option?

Comment: @masud_moni: What would be "better"? The query is straight-forward: look for cities matching the pattern. What would you consider a "better" way?

Comment: If I had a better option, I would have already posted here..See..you have edited the updated one. I was just asking for learning...I did not mean to hurt you.Hope you understand. God bless..